# Quando atualizo um componente não jsf ( html normal ) o elemento some da renderização e perde seu conteúdo

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Estou usando um elemento `<span>` que está usando uma biblioteca javascript sobre ele.

> Lembrando que as funcionalidades JSF funcionam apenas em seus elementos

Quando eu executo um "update = id_componente" (este id_componente é um componente não jsf) ele perde seu conteúdo e some da visualização.

Exemplo. Um `<span>` com "contentEditable = true" em seu estado inicial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao ser feito o update ele fica no seguinte estado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Somente o quadrado limpo sem nada..

Alguém sabe o por que desse comportamento...?

Comment: Exatamente o que você falou. Componentes JSF não funcionam bem com componentes não JSF. Troque o span por um componente JSF equivalente.

Comment: Utilizei um h:outputText e mesmo assim não funcionou.. Estou suspeitando que no update o jsf está limpando o html e a lib js não está conseguindo encontrar o elemento novamente para adicionar o estado anterior.

Estou tento que após o processamento reiniciar o campo através do javascript para limpá-lo e voltar o normal.. Mas estou achando muito estranho..

Comment: Como está o código do seu Javascript? Lembre que o nome do componente html gerado a partir do componente jsf tem um nome random, então não dá pra usar essa informação para acessá-lo.

Comment: Eu capturo via classe que adiciono a ele.. e tem um id atribuído por mim tbm.. esse definido manual muda?